# Adding Date as section header title with Core Data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to add the date a new cell was created in the form of Month, Year as the Sections header title. Below I have all of my code for the core data but seem to get the error

"cannot convert value of type `string` to expected argument type `nsdate`"
and
"use of unresolved identifier `date`"

[Core Data Model Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zStt4.png)

**Core Data Manager - PRManager.swift**

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct AddPR {
    var name = "Name"
    var desc = "Description"
    var weight = "Weight"
    var date = "Date"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

var tasks = [AddPR]()
var persistenceHelper: PersistenceHelper = PersistenceHelper()

override init(){

    let tempTasks:NSArray = persistenceHelper.list("Task")
    for res:AnyObject in tempTasks{
        tasks.append(AddPR(name:res.valueForKey("name")as! String,desc:res.valueForKey("desc") as! String,weight:res.valueForKey("weight") as! String,date:res.valueForKey("date")as! String))
    }
}


func addTask(name:String, desc: String, weight: String){

    var dicTask: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
    dicTask["name"] = name
    dicTask["desc"] = desc
    dicTask["Weight"] = weight
    **dicTask["Date"] = date**


    if(persistenceHelper.save("Task", parameters: dicTask)){
        **tasks.append(AddPR(name: name, desc: desc, weight: weight, date: date))**
    }
}

func removeTask(index:Int){

    let value:String = tasks[index].name

    if(persistenceHelper.remove("Task", key: "name", value: value)){
        tasks.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
}
```

**PersistenceHelper.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PersistenceHelper: NSObject {

var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext;

override init(){
    context = appDel.managedObjectContext
}

func save(entity: String, parameters: Dictionary<String,String> )->Bool{

    let newEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity, inManagedObjectContext: context)
    for (key, value) in parameters{
        newEntity.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    } catch _ {
        return false
    }
}

func list(entity: String ) ->NSArray{

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    let results: NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    return results
}

func remove(entity:String, key:String, value:String)->Bool{

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(key) = %@", value)
    let results: NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    if(results.count>0){

        let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
        context.deleteObject(res)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch _ {
        }
        return true
    }

    return false
}
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit


class PRViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tblTasks : UITableView!

//For persisting data
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tblTasks.reloadData()
    tblTasks.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PRTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PRTableCell")
    tblTasks.tableFooterView = UIView()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tblTasks.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{



    return 1

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter() // This is slightly inefficient for a large number of rows because setting up NSDateFormatter is expensive. You could make this a property.
    formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

    let sectionHeaderDate = taskMgr.tasks[section].date
```

This is where I get the cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type nsdate error

```
    **let dateCreated = formatter.stringFromDate(sectionHeaderDate)**
    return dateCreated
}

//Define how our cells look - 2 lines a heading and a subtitle
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let identifier = "PRTableCell"
    var cell: PRTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? PRTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PRTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? PRTableViewCell
    }


//        Assign the contents of our var "items" to the textLabel of each cell
//        cell.textLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

    cell.PRLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.NotesLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
    cell.WeightLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].weight + "lb"






    return cell



}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

        taskMgr.removeTask(indexPath.row)
        tblTasks.reloadData()
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        let numberOfSections = taskMgr.tasks.count
        return numberOfSections
    }





}
}
```

**AddCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class addPRTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var txtPR: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtDesc: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var txtWeight: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    txtPR.delegate = self


}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return 5
}


func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let maxLength = 25
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}



//    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
//        
//        
//        // Configure the cell...
//        
//        
//        
//        return cell
//    }

//Button Clicked
@IBAction func btnAddTask(sender : UIBarButtonItem){
    if (txtPR.text == ""){
        //Task Title is blank, do not add a record
    } else {
        //add record
        let name: String = txtPR.text!
        let description: String = txtDesc.text!
        let weight: String = txtWeight.text!
        taskMgr.addTask(name, desc: description, weight: weight)

        //dismiss keyboard and reset fields

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        txtPR.text = nil
        txtDesc.text = nil
        txtWeight.text = nil


    }
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 246/255, green: 75/255, blue: 55/255, alpha: 1.0)  //make the text white
}
```

Comment: In CoreData you are trying to save a Date (`NSDate`), but in your dictionary, you are only storing strings..... `Dictionary<String,String>`

Comment: ... and your addTask method uses a "date" variable ("dicTask["Date"] = date") but "date" is neither defined as a parameter for the function, nor a local variable, nor a property.

Comment: that's a lot of code with little indication of which lines cause the issues - try to focus your question and help us to help you, we don't all have time to read hundreds of lines of not very well formatted code to try to work out what's wrong

Comment: @wain Errors are highlighted in astrix

Comment: @WilliamGP What code should I change then in order for it to accept 'NSDate' ?

Comment: Your model correctly has the `date` field defined as a `Date`. This means you need to assign an `NSDate` NOT a `String` when dealing with this field. Your code in `addTask` assigns a `String` to the `date` property - this is wrong. You have done this because you create a `dicTask` dictionary that expects `<String, String>` - this will not work when one of the types is an `NSDate`. Your `AddPR` struct wrongly defines `date` as a `String` not an `NSDate`. Your code in "ViewController" that I created in a previous question for you is fine. Use the Xcode debugger to fix these obvious errors.

Comment: @RoboticCat Ok. That makes sense. But when I try to add NSDate to the dictionary '<String, String, NSDate>' It gives me an error saying I've got 3 but expected 2.

Comment: That's not a `Dictionary` - a `Dictionary` can only be 2 things: `<key, object>`. Here's hint: don't put the info into a dictionary, use the `AddPR` struct you have already created instead. I think the core issue here is that you need to follow a few tutorials before continuing with your app. I strongly urge you to follow `Developing iOS 8 Apps With Swift` from Stanford on iTunesU (or `Developing iOS 9 Apps With Swift` but this is currently incomplete). Alternatively look at http://www.raywenderlich.com